# Django, UserProfile inheritance nightmare?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-admin, django-registration

I'm using both `django-userena` and `django-facebook` as my main registration apps.

Let's inherit my own `UserProlfile` from both of them:

```
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from django_facebook.models import FacebookProfileModel


class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile , FacebookProfileModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='user_profile')
    department     = models.ForeignKey('Department' , null = True , blank = True , related_name=_('user'))
    name           = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    birthday       = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(UserProfile):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course , null = True, blank = True, related_name = _('student'))
```

Now, whenever I want go see the Student within the Django Admin, I get this error :

```
Exception Value: No such column: profiles_userprofile.about_me
```

But, it EXISTS !! this is the output of `./manage.py sqlall profiles` :

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "profiles_userprofile" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "mugshot" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "privacy" varchar(15) NOT NULL,

    "about_me" text, ## Her it is !!!

    "facebook_id" bigint UNIQUE,
    "access_token" text NOT NULL,
    "facebook_name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "facebook_profile_url" text NOT NULL,
    "website_url" text NOT NULL,
    "blog_url" text NOT NULL,
    "image" varchar(255),
    "date_of_birth" date,
    "gender" varchar(1),
    "raw_data" text NOT NULL,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "department_id" integer,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "birthday" date NOT NULL
)
;
```

I'm so so confused .. can anybody gives me a hint please ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlall` only tells you the SQL that *would* be sent, if you were running `syncdb` for the first time. It does *not* give you the actual state of the database. You must actually run `syncdb` to have the tables created. Further, if any of the tables already existed, `syncdb` will *not* make any changes to the table(s); it only creates tables, never alters them.

If you need to alter the table, you will either have to manually run SQL on your database, or use something like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to do a migration.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sqlite3. These are design decisions made inside Django that have good reasoning behind them.